# 'Error during template compile of 'AppModule' Expression form not supported' issue when creating build of my angular 5 project

Tags: angular5

I am trying to create build of my angular 5 app, but it showing following error

> Error during template compile of 'AppModule Expression form not supported.

I am using reg expression for creating dynamic paths for routing.Following is my code in app.module that cause above error.

```
{       
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("luxury-cruises/x-to-x-x", /^luxury-cruises\/[a-zA-Z-]+-to-[a-zA-Z-]+-[0-9-]+$/),
        component: RcycVoyagesComponent
    },
  {     
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("luxury-x-cruises", /^luxury-[a-zA-Z-]+-cruises$/),
        component: RcycRegionComponent
    },  
    {
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("luxury-x-cruises/cruises-from-x-x", /^luxury-[a-zA-Z-]+-cruises\/cruises-from-[a-zA-Z-]+-[a-zA-Z-]+$/),
        component: RcycPortsComponent
    },
    {
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("luxury-x-cruises/cruises-from-x-x/porttabs", /^luxury-[a-zA-Z-]+-cruises\/cruises-from-[a-zA-Z-]+-[a-zA-Z-]+\/[a-zA-Z-]+$/),
        component: RcycPortsComponent
    },
    {
        matcher: ComplexUrlMatcher("experience/suites/porttabs", /experience\/suites\/[a-zA-Z-]+$/),
        component: RcycSuitesComponent
    },
```

how can I solve this issue?